# How can I handle NULL values while doing datetime comparisons?

Tags: mysql, sql

My goal is to work out how many accounts there have been on my website at specific times. I allow accounts to be cancelled at anytime, but if they were cancelled after the month I'm looking at then I would still like them to appear as they were active at that snapshot in time.

My `accounts` table which looks like:

```
   --------------------------------------------------
        id                         | int
        signUpDate                 | varchar
        cancellationTriggeredDate  | datetime (NULLABLE)
   --------------------------------------------------
```

I wrote a select statement to accomplish this goal which looks like:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS January_2020
FROM
    Accounts
WHERE
    STR_TO_DATE(signUpDate, '%d/%m/%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE('31/01/2020', '%d/%m/%Y')
    AND cancellationTriggeredDate <= '2020-01-31 00:00:00'
```

The expected results would be 3, this is how many accounts I had in January and have not been cancelled after January. The actual results is 0. I believe this is because not all of my accounts have a cancellation date set, but I'm not sure how to handle this.

To make it easier to get help, I have created a SQL Fiddle including sample data and schema.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64f3e3

Comment: Why are you storing dates as strings?  If you store the values using the correct types, then your queries will be much simpler -- and less prone to error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I understand, unfortunately this decision was made years ago so I have many accounts with dates as strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date comparison needs to be correct for the cancellation date.

Then you can use `OR` to handle `NULL`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS January_2020
FROM Accounts
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(signUpDate, '%d/%m/%Y') <= '2020-01-31' and
      (cancellationTriggeredDate > '2020-01-31' OR
       cancellationTriggeredDate IS NULL
      )
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64f3e3/8) is the db<>fiddle.  Note that the above gives the users who are active at eactly 2020-01-31 00:00:00 -- that is, at the beginning of the day.  There are different things that you might mean:

- Customers active at exactly 2020-01-31 00:00:00
- Customers active at exactly 2020-02-01 00:00:00
- Customers active for the entire day of 2020-01-31
- Customers active for the entire month of 2020-01
- Customers active at any time during the month of 2020-01

All of these use basically the same logic, just by tweaking the specific comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution - you can use `CASE WHEN` and initialize `cancellationTriggeredDate` with a hypothetically higher date (i.e. end of this century) before taking this field for comparison in `WHERE` predicate.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS January_2020
FROM
    Accounts
WHERE
    STR_TO_DATE(signUpDate, '%d/%m/%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE('31/01/2020', '%d/%m/%Y')
    AND CASE WHEN cancellationTriggeredDate IS NULL THEN '2099-12-31' ELSE cancellationTriggeredDate END  > '2020-01-31 00:00:00'
```